# This code returns 301 permanently moved while the same script worked properly

Tags: javascript, java, http, http-status-code-301

this is part of java script to collect some data in .xls file from a website (https://web.expasy.org/protparam/). The website has a box in which we put some character, then it computes and redirects to another URL (https://web.expasy.org/cgi-bin/protparam/protparam). The whole java script was working fine but for some time it doesn't work, I tried to diagnose the problem and now I get the error on console

```
""<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://web.expasy.org/cgi-bin/protparam/protparam">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>"
```

May someone resolve this please?
One thing I must declare : I am not from core programming field and thus I need your help.

```
//initializing the url 
URL siturl = new URL("http://web.expasy.org/cgi-bin/protparam/protparam");
//opening the siturl connection
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
conn = (HttpURLConnection)siturl.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setFollowRedirects(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(data.length())); 
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
//setting the output condition to true for printing the contents
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
// used to convert character to bytes
wr.write(data);
//System.out.println(data);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
// Get the response
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("xlsresult.xls",true));
// printing the results to a text file
//out.write(data);            
out.write(profilename+ "\t");
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the connection as HTTP but the page is HTTPS now and therefore sends you a HTTP 301 (because it's now on https://web.expasy.org/cgi-bin/protparam/protparam instead of http://web.expasy.org/cgi-bin/protparam/protparam). At least that would be my guess (I don't work a lot with HTTP).

Changeing

```
    URL siturl = new URL("http://web.expasy.org/cgi-bin/protparam/protparam");
```

to

```
    URL siturl = new URL("https://web.expasy.org/cgi-bin/protparam/protparam");
```

will probably do the trick.

Comment: Just tried it and get an HTTP 200 with some valid html code. Full test of mine is on https://pastebin.com/xjfnqNW7

Comment: When I add **https** in URL of the program script as per your suggestion, I get the following error - Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at Protparam.main(Protparam.java:174)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? I Tested on Java 11 and if a interpret the exception right your version of SSL is likely older than the of the server.

Comment: it is Java 7, jdk1.7.0_80

Comment: Its working, I installed Java 14 and it works fine. tnx